# Command line command doesn't work in Python - doesn't send file

Tags: php, python, youtube

I am using the youtube-upload command line script to (oddly enough) upload a video to youtube. I'm passing in my variables from PHP, into Python, which generates the command string and passes it to

```
result = subprocess.call(copmmand, shell=True)
```

The command generated by my script is as follows:

```
youtube-upload --description="$(< \sites/default/files/descriptions/5799.txt)" --title="Title" --category=Music sites/default/files/videos/5799.mp4
```

or (youtube-upload documentation lists with a prefixed backslash, either achieves the same result)

```
youtube-upload --description="$(< sites/default/files/descriptions/5799.txt)" --title="Title" --category=Music sites/default/files/videos/5799.mp4
```

Now the script works perfectly aside from the description text file is not passed. Outside of python, in the command line, it does it. I've tried passing the full path of the file too...but it's not happening.

There are no errors in the stack trace output

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm passing it as a file because when I tried to pass in a string from php in the json object, I couldn't retrieve it on the other end. Can anyone maybe point me at the right direction for this issue?

Comment: Is the start of the path to the description wrong? `\sites/` instead of `/sites/`

Comment: No, that backslash was just in the documentation for youtube-upload. I'm assuming it's escaping something.

I've tried it with and without, in either case it works in command line but doesn't in python. The full path is /home/mmallett/Sites/Soul/sites/default/files/descriptions/5799.txt, which also doesn't work

Will edit my question to show this

Comment: Only thing further I can suggest to help debug it is change `subprocess.call` to `subprocess.check_output` and then `print result` to see what it returns from the command line that could help shed some light on it.

Comment: Nothing new from that unfortunately.

Comment: Only other things I can think of are file permissions (make sure it is readable by everyone) and try not using shell=True (will have to separate items into list, can use `shlex.split`).  Also curious by what you mean  "when I tried to pass in a string from php in the json object, I couldn't retrieve it on the other end". What JSON object?

Comment: I am passing the arguments from php into the python script through a json object. I'm new to python so my terminology is probably off.

I've decided to use another approach. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it work that way. With the JSON object you should be able to run `json.loads` on it and turn it into a dictionary. Then retrieve the item you are looking for via it's name. If you do want more direction on it just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got around this by opening the file into a variable and passing that into the command instead

```
    with open ("/home/mmallett/Sites/GottaLoveSoul/sites/default/files/descriptions/" + nid + ".txt", "r") as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

    upload = 'youtube-upload --description="' + data + '" --title="' + title + '" --category=Music ' + video

result = subprocess.check_output(upload, shell=True)
```